# How to print Hexagram in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to print the first hexagram [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_1) in Perl.

The code below doesn't generate any errors, but doesn't print any hexagrams either.

```
use warnings;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

print "\x{4DC0}\n";
```

I was hoping to see this "䷀" not "Σ╖Ç".

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure your terminal is expecting UTF-8?

Comment: The `use open` call is unnecessary, since you are not opening any handles in that scope. Alternatively if you add `':std'` as a parameter to `use open`, you don't need the `binmode`. Also, either way you should pass `:encoding(UTF-8)`, as `:utf8` and `:encoding(utf8)` reference the internal encoding layer for Perl and should generally not be used in code.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the code page and that helped. I'm getting a little white rectangle now, which I guess is an improvement. Have you ever tried this in a canvas Tk object? This started out as a test to get to that goal.

Comment: Not all character glyphs are available in all fonts. You might have more luck if you explicitly set the font on the widget

Answer (score 4):

You tell Perl your terminal is expecting UTF-8, but your terminal appears to expect one of the following:<sup>[1]</sup>

- [cp437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)
- [cp860](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_860)
- [cp861](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_861)
- [cp863](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_863)
- [cp865](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_865)

Seeing as these are all Windows code pages, I presume the terminal in question is a Windows console. If so, you can find out which encoding is expected using either of these commands:

```
chcp
```

```
perl -le"use Win32; print Win32::GetACP()"
```

Prepend `cp` to the number to get a name you can use with the Encode module (which is used by the `:encoding` layer).

Knowing the expected encoding won't help you, however. None of the character sets of these encodings contains "䷀", so your terminal can't display "䷀" without change.

You can switch the encoding expected by a Windows console to UTF-8 by issuing the following command:

```
chcp 65001
```

You may have to adjust the font in the console's properties.

---

1. I obtained the list of possible encodings using the following program:

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use feature qw( say );
   use utf8;
   use Encode qw( decode encode_utf8 );

   my $output = encode_utf8("\x{4DC0}");
   my $displayed = "Σ╖Ç";

   for my $encoding (Encode->encodings(":all")) {
      defined( my $got = eval { decode($encoding, $output, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC) } )
         or next;

      say $encoding if $output eq $displayed;
   }
   ```

   (Make sure the file is encoded using UTF-8.)

Comment: You are indeed correct this is a Windows CMD window. My first attempt with your code gave me: ```Malformed UTF-8 character: \xc7\x22 (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x22, immediately after start byte 0xc7; need 2 bytes, got 1) at PrintHexagram.pl line 8.
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at PrintHexagram.pl line 8.```

Comment: 1) The code I posted is of no use to you. You should keep using your existing code. 2) You got that error because you didn't save the file using UTF-8 as directed.

Comment: chcp helped some

Comment: I've got to figure out how to do UTF-8 in my editor. I know it can do it, but obviously this is my first experience with UTF-8.

Comment: The program I posted needs to be saved using UTF-8 because it contains non-ASCII chars, which is also why `use utf8;` is used. None of that is relevant to you. I simply included the program for future reference.